# Search Scope IsDocument=1 Required - Shows incorrect number for Item Count

Tags: search-scope

I have over 40000 documents in various library for a site collection. When setting up scope for this (IsDocument=1) i only see 74 in the item count. Full crawl is set to run every night. Where should I look to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Item Count on the Search Scopes is only an estimate and can be wildly out.

When you perform a search in your search center on the scope for all documents do you get the full ~40,000 items or just 74?

To do a search for all documents use a part of the URL.  For example if your site URL is http://www.contoso.com/sites/Mysite then do a search for "Contoso" to match all documents.

Comment: at the site collection i do see the correct number. it could be claim based enabled and central admin is classic based.